# Generate outline effect on image using css3

Tags: javascript, css

How can I generate in realtime this outline effect similar to this image using css3 or javascript?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCQl8.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Here is an similar effect achieved with filter and background-blending

```css
div {
        width: 180px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.test {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/1OEnuKF.jpg), url(http://i.imgur.com/1OEnuKF.jpg); 
    background-position: 0px 0px, 3px 3px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: difference;
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px)invert(1);
}

.target {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/1OEnuKF.jpg); 
    background-position: top right;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
```

The left part of the image is achieved from the original image; the right hand is the target image.

Answer (score 0):

there are some filter effects in CSS3 , **only for webkit**

I've no idea how to use them to make the effect you showed
but I think they can help 

here is a link that you can test CSS3 filters and get the css code
http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html 

and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) you can see it's Browser compatibility

hope that help's

Comment: Firefox now implement them too, since [last version Firefox 35](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) (MDN) ([caniuse - filter](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter)). Won't be in [Fx ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) till september or october 2015 though